# Why do STM32 MCUs divide RAM into SRAM1 and SRAM2?

Tags: stm32, arm, ram, sram

Why do STM32 MCUs divide RAM into SRAM1 and SRAM2? They seem contiguous, so that I could simply configure my linker to treat both as just one chunk of RAM.

Should I do that? If not, how do I tell the linker (via a `.ld` script) that there are two different regions of RAM?

**Update:** I'm using STM32F446RE.  My current linker.ld says `LENGTH = 112k`.  There's 16KB that I don't know how to tell the linker about.

Comment: Not all STM32 have more than one SRAM block and even the modela with more than one don't neceasarily have them contiguous. Please specifcy which exact STM32 model you are talkint about, e.g. STM32 F103RB, as all the numbers and letters are important to specify what kind of memories it has and how much.

Comment: @Justme Done - see edit.

Answer (score 10):

> Why do STM32 MCUs divide RAM into SRAM1 and SRAM2?

Without the datasheet to the specific part, here's a generic answer:

If both SRAM blocks are connected to the bus matrix it is usually possible to access both in the same cycle, ie the CPU can load both instruction and data in one cycle if one block is used for code and the other for data.

If you use high throughput DMA this is also a nice performance feature because the DMA can hit one SRAM block while the CPU uses the other block without having to wait.

Each SRAM block may have different features, including (or not) the following:

- Data retention in deep sleep when the CPU is completely powered off
- Gate clock/power to one block to save power if you don't use it
- Different bus connections (one SRAM block can be faster than the other or have dual ports)
- Hardware parity for extra reliability
- Write protection

Answer (score 8):

SRAM1 and SRAM2 have different properties.
The presentation ["STM32L4 - SYSCFG"](https://www.st.com/resource/en/product_training/stm32l4_system_syscfg.pdf) says that

- SRAM2 is always accessed with zero waitstates,
- SRAM2 supports parity checks,
- SRAM2 contents can be retained in standby, and
- SRAM2 can be write-protected, read-protected (agains JTAG/debuggers), and automatically cleared on reset.

So you would choose to place certain code or data in SRAM2 for performance, safety, or security reasons.

---

To place something into SRAM2, you have to define a region and section in the linker script (take care that no other region is using the same address range), for example:

```
RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 96K
RAM_2 (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 32K

...

.ram2_bss :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.ram2_bss)
    *(.ram2_bss*)
} >RAM_2
```

… and tell the compiler to use that section:

```
static uint8_t __attribute__((section(".ram2_bss"), used)) myData[42];
```

---

If you want to use the entire SRAM as one contiguous region, then you can define that region in the linker script.

Comment: Properties of L4 are different than the F4 in question. Nevertheless, it shows that the areas can have wildly different properties.

Answer (score 5):

For the F446RE, there is said to be 128 KB of RAM, divided into 112KB of SRAM1 and 16KB of SRAM2.

They are said to run at equal speed, zero wait states.

They are also arranged in one contiguous 128KB memory area.

In the reference manual, SRAM1 is called the Main SRAM, and SRAM2 is called the Auxiliary SRAM.

The only difference is that the bus matrix connects I and D buses to SRAM1 but not to SRAM2.

I-bus is used by the CPU core to fetch instructions so for reading program code. D-bus is used by the CPU core for "literal loads", to fetch code or related data from memory.

The S-bus that connecta to both SRAM areas is used fo generic data access, fetching code is possible but less efficient.

As the SRAMs are divided into two separate memory peripherals, it also means it is possible to have two memory transactions at the same time, such as USB peripheral could be accessing SRAM1 while CPU is accessing SRAM2 at the same time.

Comment: Interesting.  So would it make sense to just tell the linker to view the whole thing (SRAM1 and SRAM2) combined as one address space? That would start the stack in SRAM2, I believe, since it starts at the end.

Comment: @SRobertJames the stack is only located at the end of RAM if your linker script puts it there. It could be located anywhere in RAM.